# Command in bash shell script to find path to that script?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, script, path

Is there a command to go inside a bash `.sh` script that will provide the full path to the directory containing that script?

Answer (score 3):

See the answers on [Get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself). The accepted one recommends

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
```

but reading all the answers gives a lot of alternatives (and insights into how shells work).

Answer (score 2):

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself) do not always contain best practices, so if you just want the directory echoed on the screen (even when it contains spaces):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "My Script is being run from here: $(dirname "$0")"
```

If you want it into a variable and want `.` expanded to the full path, you need GNU Readlink first so:

1. Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. Install GNU CoreUtils:

   ```
   brew install coreutils
   ```
3. Use the following script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   szMyPath=$(dirname "$0")

   if [[ $szMyPath =~ ^. ]]; then 
     szMyPath="$(dirname "$(greadlink -f "$0")")" 
   fi

   echo "$szMyPath"
   ```

Comment: The second, longer version is giving me an error: `readlink: illegal option -- f`.

Comment: @murray Edited. My apologies for the error.